# Use 3rd-party apps from an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, apk, android-instant-run

I wanted to use a 3rd-party app with an intent but application is not installed on user's device. Something like Android Instant Run but apk are included in application or If it isn't possible, How can I install apk on user's? However can I install application silently without Package Installer?
I'll be appreciated if anybody answer my questions.

Comment: You can't install packages silently, that would be a security.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to use a 3rd-party app with an intent but application is not installed on user's device.

Ask the user to install it.

> Something like Android Instant Run but apk are included in application

Nothing like that exists, sorry.

> However can I install application silently without Package Installer?

Fortunately, that is not possible, for security reasons.